# FK constraint is incorrectly formed ERROR

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, create-table

I got the following error message whenever I try to import this sql file to my localhost

> (#1005 - Can't create table `hostel_management_system`.`Hostel_Manager` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"))

Here is the sql:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Hostel_Manager`;

CREATE TABLE `Hostel_Manager` (
  `Hostel_man_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Fname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Lname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Mob_no` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Hostel_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `Pwd` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
  `Isadmin` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Hostel_man_id`),
  UNIQUE (`Username`),
  KEY `Hostel_id` (`Hostel_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `Hostel_Manager_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Hostel_id`) REFERENCES `Hostel` (`Hostel_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


LOCK TABLES `Hostel_Manager` WRITE;

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Hostel table :

```
CREATE TABLE `Hostel` (
  `Hostel_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Hostel_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `current_no_of_rooms` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `No_of_rooms` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `No_of_students` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Hostel_id`)
)
```

Why do I get that error and how to fix it?

Comment: Please show us the `create table` statement for table `Hostel` as well.

Comment: sorry i forgot to add it....

Comment: Please, pick the right tags for your question. SQL Server is irrelevant here as the code isn't T-SQL. Picking the right tags will yield quick and accurate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the parent and children column have the same datatype and length, and the parent column is a primary colum, so that's not the issue here.

I suspect that the problem is the `charset`. `Hostel_Manager` specifies a default `charset`, while `Hostel` does not. If the default charset of your database is something else than `latin1`, then the foreign is malformed.

I would recommend explictly aligning the `charset` so it is the same for both tables (either remove both, or declare the same value).

Note that both tables also need to have the same storage engine. `InnoDB` is the default, so that should not be an issue, but you might want to explictly align that as well (in case the default of your database is `MyISAM`).